# Mongodb document update error with Codeigniter: Mod on _id not allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, codeigniter-2, php-mongodb

I'm trying to use Codeigniter with [codeigniter-mongodb-library/tree/v2](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library) in order to connect with mongo and Update documents with this structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("50fd8bd460e958aa38000002"),
"created_at" : 1358793684,
"updated_at" : 1358793684,
"is_active" : 0,
"memberships" : [
    {
    }
],
"first_models" : [
    [ ]
],
"second_models" : [
    [ ]
],
"pages" : [
    [ ]
]
}
```

All I want is Update some document by it's given _id. Particularly **I need to add elements inside "first_models" array**. From my Codeigniter model I'm calling this:

```
$result = $this->mongo_db
->push(array('_id' => '50fd8bd460e958aa38000002'),array('first_models' => array('Some text here'))) 
->update($this->collections['sites']);
```

I'm getting this error when I try to Update one specific document:

```
Mod on _id not allowed
```

Seems there is some conflict with the given _id... I'm missing something and I don't know what :(
I'm using Mongodb 2.2.2 with Codeigniter 2.1.3, PHP5.4 and Apache2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going in wrong direction with that. Finally [@Rajan](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/issues/96#issuecomment-12594615) points me to right solution:

```
$updated = $this->mongo_db->where('_id', new MongoId($id))
->set($data)
->update('mycollection');
```

You can see, using `set` instead `push`, and referencing object id with `new MongoId($id)` :-)